# What is a real life example of non-rectangular and N-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is a real life example of non-rectangular and N-dimensional array. I know you could use 3-dimensional for gaming but not sure when you're going to use more than that, also I never saw an example of non-rectangular arrays.

Comment: "Non-rectangular" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: [OLAP "Cubes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube) can be N-d (basically Cubes of Cubes if thinking of it visually): "Because there can be more than three dimensions in an OLAP system the term hypercube is sometimes used."

Comment: @Jimmy That's for N-d. For just a jagged array, one very common example is a Hash Map that uses a Linked List for collision resolution. (While a Linked List if often used because of various properties, it can be substituted for an Array trivially.)

Answer (score 2):

High-dimensional arrays (3D, 4D, etc.) often arise in the context of [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) algorithms, in which they are used to store intermediate results in a larger computation so that an overall result can be computed.  For sample, the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), when used to compute all-pairs shortest paths, uses a three-dimensional array to cache intermediate values as they are computed.  The resulting 3D array is then used to read off the shortest paths between any two nodes in the graph.

Jagged arrays are sometimes used to represent [upper-triangular matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_triangular_matrix) in matrix operations like the [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) or in Gaussian elimination.  They also form the basis of some data structures like the exponential array.

Hope this helps!